# Embed PowerBI in app authenticated with Azure AD v2

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, openid, powerbi-embedded

I'm building a Web App that is using Azure AD for login and want to embed PowerBI in a client written in React.

I have a simple express application using the node-openid-client and passport to authenticate with the Azure AD v2 endpoint. This then renders out a react application and then we rehydrate it on the client. The issue I'm facing is that I can't get 1 token that has permissions for both my application and Power BI. When I add the Power BI permissions to my claims it even changes the audience of the token from my app to PowerBI (00000009-0000-0000-c000-000000000000) so it doesn't validate.

I'm using this package in the client: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-powerbi

Is there any way I can get a token that covers all the permissions in my Azure AD Application to use on the client?

Relevant code:

```
Issuer.discover(`https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/v2.0`)
.then(async adIssuer => {
  const eidClient = new adIssuer.Client({
    redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    token_endpoint_auth_method: "client_secret_basic"
  });

  passport.use(
    "oidc",
    new Strategy(
      {
        client: microsoftClient,
        params: {
          client_id: CLIENT_ID,
          redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
          scope: "openid",
          response_type: "code",
          response_mode: "query",
          state: "testing",
          nonce: 10000
        }
      },
      (tokenset, user, done) => {
        done(null, {
          access_token: tokenset.access_token,
          id_token: tokenset.id_token,
          expires_at: tokenset.expires_at,
          id: tokenset.sub,
          ...user
        });
      }
    )
  );
})
.catch(e => console.error(e));


app
.get("/auth", passport.authenticate("oidc"))
.get(
  "/auth/cb",
  passport.authenticate("oidc", {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.status(401).send("Login");
  }
)
```

If there is anything missing just ask and I'll add it

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do this with one single token. You need a separate token to access Power BI.

Comment: What's the best way to get the second token if I have signed in once? I don't want to redirect the user multiple times in the OIDC flow.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the way you use to authenticate. I'm using [ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) and [AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet) to do this, and with this approach it is possible to generate tokens for different services, with or without prompting the user for credentials.

Comment: Thanks a lot, might have a look into msal for this then as I'm using the v2 endpoint.